# how to add dynamic array of item in ExpandoObject Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, uiswitch, expandoobject

i want to add dynamically selected items in ExpandoObject then print it in the form of json value. if i selected 2values, it is printing only the last value 2times.My problem is whatever im selecting it prints last value only.

My code:
Declaration

```
 dynamic output = new List<dynamic>();
 dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
 List<int> selected = new List<int>();
```

switch toggle function:

```
 private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        var switch1 = (Switch)sender;
        var human = (Human)switch1.BindingContext;
        var id = human.retail_modified_item_id;
        var name = human.name;
        var old_price = human.old_price;
        var new_price = human.new_price;
        if (switch1.IsToggled)
        {
            if (!selected.Contains(id))
            {
                selected.Add(id);
                foo.id = id;
                foo.name = name;
                foo.old_price=old_price;
                foo.new_price=new_price;
                output.Add(foo);                 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (selected.Contains(id)) selected.Remove(id);
        }
    }
```

Printing Json value ;

```
 string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
 Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

My output is:

> [{"id":1000739,"name":"Hashbrowns","old_price":0.99,"new_price":8.5},{"id":1000739,"name":"Hashbrowns","old_price":0.99,"new_price":8.5}]

if i selected 2values, it is printing only the last value 2times.

Comment: Well described contents but forgot to asked question, what's your question actually?

Comment: i added it in last line.okay i updated it

Comment: May be because you are removing the item from selected using `selected.Remove(id)` but not from `output` at the same time so value removed from the `selected` but same remains in `output` and added the same again

Comment: but i didn't remove anything..if same id is presented then only i removed

Comment: does it work now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();

you declare global variables here,so the second time you call the following code, you are reassuming the first foo and adding it again, so there are two identical items in the output List.

```
foo.id = id;
foo.name = name;
foo.old_price=old_price;
foo.new_price=new_price;
output.Add(foo);
```

you could change like this :

```
if (!selected.Contains(id))
    {
        selected.Add(id);
        dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject(); // local variables
        foo.id = id;
        foo.name = name;
        foo.old_price=old_price;
        foo.new_price=new_price;
        output.Add(foo);                 
    }
```